# Disable MAC quarantine to distribute customized Firefox ESR by network

Tags: firefox

I am preparing Firefox ESR build with custom default addons. The problem is that after I follow the instructions from https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/deploying-firefox-customizations-macos and:
1. Upload customized Firefox.app into cloud server
2. Download it on the client machine
It can not be run until removing "quarantine" manually from terminal with  (same step as required to be done to edit container)

```
xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine Firefox.app
```

But this ff with plugin supposed to be used by managers and highly likely to evade this technical step. Such build runs without facing quarantine on any machine if quarantine was removed and app was copied from e.g. usb drive (looks expected for me)

So, is that possible to evade custom ff to be 'quarantined' after downloading?

Comment: How do the custom builds get to the other Macs? Donyou push them overnight or do the users manually install them from a website?

Comment: @nohillside I would like to send download link to users and ask them to download it manually